# Email text from field if "Resolved" is selected

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Currently I have a Google Form for recording issues within an organization, the responses are recorded on a Google Sheet. I have a column on my sheet called "status" which is a drop-down box with 3 options: "New", "Working on", and "Done". I also have a column called "resolved notes".

How would I go about making a script that, if "Done" is selected from the drop-down box, then the "resolved notes" data would be emailed to the persons who logged the issue?

PS the person who logged the issue has there email addresses stored in the D column

Comment: You'll need to write a function, and then under the Resources menu in the code editor choose, "Current Project Triggers".  Add a new trigger that runs when the form is submitted.

Comment: [Google documentation - installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)